# Make all key pressed event to ctrlKey:true on xtermjs

Tags: javascript, keyboard-events, xtermjs

I check all key press by using:

```
term.onKey(function (e) {
  console.log(e,'yes')
})
```

Currently, every I pressed any key will `ctrlKey` value will depend on I pressed or not. example:

```
domEvent: KeyboardEvent
    altKey: false
    bubbles: true
    cancelBubble: false
    cancelable: true
    charCode: 0
    code: "KeyV"
    composed: true
    ctrlKey: false
    currentTarget: null
    defaultPrevented: true
    detail: 0
    eventPhase: 0
    isComposing: false
    isTrusted: true
    key: "v"
```

Any way to make any key pressed will be changed to `ctrlKey:true` ?
I want to create control button helper for mobile user. so when helper active alway turn on controll.

I tried to change directly using `e.domEvent.ctrlKey=true` but not working